# Coefficients in expansion of a classical symmetric polynomial

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials

If we expand  \begin{equation} P_3(x_1,\ldots, x_n):=\Pi_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n} (x_i+x_j+x_k), \end{equation} then \begin{equation} P_3 = \sum_\alpha \sum_{\mathcal{O}(\alpha)} c_\alpha x_1^{\alpha_{\sigma(1)}}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_{\sigma(n)}}, \end{equation}  where

$\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n)$ ranges over certain partitions \begin{equation} \alpha_1+\cdots + \alpha_n = \binom{n}{3} \end{equation} of $\binom{n}{3}$, $\alpha_1\geq \alpha_2\cdots \geq \alpha_n$, for which $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots + \alpha_k \leq \binom{n}{3}-\binom{n-k}{3}$ for each $k\geq 1$, and

\begin{equation} \mathcal{O}(\alpha)=\{(\alpha_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, \alpha_{\sigma(n)})\mid \sigma\in S_n\} \end{equation} is the orbit of $\alpha$ under the symmetric group action on $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

**Question:** What are values of the coefficients $c_\alpha$ mod 2? For instance, if $n=4$, then it is not horrible to compute that $c_\alpha \equiv 0$ for $\alpha=(2,2,0,0),\, (2,1,1,0)$ -- with integer values of 2 and 4, respectively -- while $c_\alpha\equiv 1$ for $\alpha=(1,1,1,1),\, (3,1,0,0)$ -- with integer values of 9 and 1, respectively.

This would seem to be a quite classical question, and as I am no expert in the field, I would be very happy to know of any reference.

Of course, $c_\alpha=1$ if $\alpha=(\binom{n-1}{2},\binom{n-2}{2}, \ldots, \binom{2}{2}, 0,0)$, so I don't care about that.

Comment: In the expansion of $P_3$, $k$ should be $n$.

Comment: The conditions on $\alpha$ can be strengthened. I would say that $\alpha_n+\alpha_{n-1}+\dots+\alpha_{k+1}\leq {n\choose 3}-{k\choose 3}$...